# Get parsys name with sightly (cq5 & aem)

Tags: aem, sightly

Is there a way to get the parsys name when a component is added to the page?

I have two parsys on the page (name it header / footer) if I drop the same component I would like different functionality dependent on where it was dropped. All I need to know if that information is available to the children components.

I am looking for some docs if there are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What can help you is the path of your dropped element, if you named the header parsys header your child will be dropped under /content/somewebsitetree/somePage/jcr:content/header

If it's footer it will be /content/somewebsitetree/somePage/jcr:content/footer

Hope this helps a bit....

Comment: Yup! that helps and I was able to get the parsys information by using "getParent()" however I am now stuck by accessing the data within my component. I am opening a different thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476918/aem-cq5-working-with-information-within-a-component